# Handling Multiple SOAP Actions in Tibco BW 5

Tags: tibco, tibco-designer

How do I go about creating a SOAP service in Tibco BW 5 with only one endpoint with multiple SOAP actions which can be invoked to provide different services just like how different endpoints in the same WSDL can provide different services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what are you trying to achieve. For me it sounds like you need to create one EndPoint with multiple operations.

In Tibco designer:

1) right click on the folder where you want to create wsdl-> Add resource->WSDL->WSDL

2) right click on wsdl->Add resource->WSDL->PortType

3) right click on created PortType->Add resource -> Operation

repeat step 3 for each operation that you need to create

[image]

then you need to generate SOAP service from wsdl.

here is good tutorial how to create SOAP web service http://tutorialspedia.com/step-by-step-developing-soap-web-service-in-tibco/ You need to create multiple operations on step5.